# How can I access an element from an array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ow_rhF3sibKL3OAQRXpK6LLZDjMOhW-5DKyWWiN5iZg/edit#gid=638513192');
var data = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Graficos'));
Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet());

var ergo = data.getRange(3,2,4,1);//B3:B6 '
```

My guess to access the elements was to call `var i = ergo[0];` but it didn't work. Do I have to declare `ergo` using a different syntax?

Comment: `data.getRange(3,2,4,1).getValues()` will give an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) on the range, which will return a 2-dimensional array.

```
var ergo = data.getRange(3,2,4,1).getValues();
```

Also, you're not coding efficiently as you're essentially duplicating actions in your first two lines. Take a look at this refactoring:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ow_rhF3sibKL3OAQRXpK6LLZDjMOhW-5DKyWWiN5iZg/edit#gid=638513192');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Graficos');
  ss.setActiveSheet(data); // There doesn't seem to be a need to do this, so maybe delete this line
  var ergo = data.getRange(3,2,4,1).getValues(); //B3:B6
}
```